# Convert captured Fiddler requests to Java

Tags: java, http, converters, fiddler

I was wondering, what is the easiest way to convert a request captured by Fiddler to Java code? For example, Fiddler captures a request, and I'm wondering if there is an easy way to turn it into Java code so that I can send the same request programmatically!

I am open to suggestions of other Chrome plugins that would work for this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the possibility of:

- Selecting all desired requests
- Open a contextual menu
- Choose "Save" and save them to a file.
  Then, you can just read the file and use Apache `HttpClient` (one option out of thousands) to build the different types of requests (GET,POST,etc) to the hosts specified in the saved file.

For instance, this is a POST request sent to SO while I was writing this answer:

```
POST http://stackoverflow.com/posts/validate-body HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 332
Accept: */*
Origin: http://stackoverflow.com
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931998/convert-captured-    fiddler-requests-to-java
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: es,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
Cookie: <<ommitted>> 
body=You+have+the+possibility+of+selecting+...
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer that this question is going to get. I've figured out how now to do it programmatically, but not converted. Thanks!